# Don't echo items that were recorded in previous values

Tags: php, mysql

Hi i have a problem retriving items from my database, I want to retrieve the data just one time and if an item was already retrieved in a previous value to not show that item

PHP

```
$select_query = "select * from posts";

$run_query = mysql_query($select_query);
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($run_query)){
$post_id = $row['post_id'];
$post_title = $row['post_title'];
$post_date = $row['post_date'];
$post_author = $row['post_author'];
$post_image = $row['post_image'];
$post_keywords = $row['post_keywords'];
$post_content = $row['post_content'];
```

HTML

```
<h1 class="centru">The Posts Author are: <?php echo $post_author; ?>
</h1>
```

EX: On the page this will be displayed: 

**Jhon**

Maria 

**Jhon**

Alex

**Jhon**

I want to be like this
**Jhon**

Maria
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want authors, use

```
SELECT DISTINCT post_author FROM posts
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `GROUP BY` functions!

```
$select_query = "select * from `posts` group by `post_author`";
```